# Changing the data of a object and the value of a parameter inside the embed from twitch

Tags: javascript, html, object

Hello I am trying to change the data of a object and the value of a parameter inside the embedding code from twitch.
I am not that good on javascript and could use some help.
I have done my research with no luck.
all help is appreciated :)

---

the embedding code that i want to change (this is a fresh embedding code, no edits)

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=thelifeisyours" bgcolor="#000000">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=thelifeisyours&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" />
</object>
```

here is the js i got so far and it doesn't work :P (remember i am a noob in js)

```
function changestream1(){
    var streamIn = document.getElementById('stream1').value;
    var objData= document.getElementById('live_embed_player_flash');
    var param = document.getElementById('param');

    objData.setAttribute("data", "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + streamIn); 
    param.setAttribute("value", "hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=" + streamIn + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25"); 
}
```

the idea is that the js will create the data in the object and the value in the parameter.

---

if you need a visual of how i am thinking this out press Link :D

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QnWvR/)

link to the website where this is going to be used
[twitchgrabber](http://twitchgrabber.0fees.net)

Comment: I have gotten a tip from a guy, which said: You would probably have to reconstruct the entire embed in JavaScript, then append or prepend it where you want it.

and since i am a beginner in js, i got no clue how :P

Comment: This won't solve the issue, but i'd avoid using the name object as a variable name, because it is a reserved variable in some programming languages. Just a tip.

Comment: kk, thanks for the tip. you saved me from starting a bad habit :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a + sign here streamIn **+** "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25"

you should check all the code, there are other erros like naming the function in lower case while calling in cameCase, check every variable, install firebug and look at the logs in the console...

This should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changestream1() {
        var streamInput = document.getElementById('streamName').value;
        var streamIn = ''; //This variable is not defined yet used on the last line of this block;
        var object = document.getElementById('live_embed_player_flash');
        var param = document.getElementById('param');
        object.setAttribute("data", "http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=" + streamInput);
        param.setAttribute("value", "hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=" + streamInput + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25" + streamIn);
}
</script>
<div id="streamHolder">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" bgcolor="#000000">
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
        <param name="allowNetworking" value="all" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" />
        <param id="param" name="flashvars" />
    </object>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="text" id="streamName" placeholder="Enter Streamer Name Here" style="width:12em;">
    <input type="button" id="button1" onclick="changestream1();" value="Change Stream">
</div>
<p>The name you enter will get put where the "streamInput" variable is in the javascript
<br>that is the general idea atleast</p>
```

Comment: still doesn't  work. and streamIn was an error. so it should be like this:  + streamInput + "&auto_play=true&start_volume=25");

it was a old variable.

Comment: hmm, it surly is adding the username, but what about updating it so it will start playing automaticly?

Comment: try removing the entire object then append it again to simulate a refresh (removeChild, appendChild), the flash object reads the values when the page loads, another solution would be putting the object inside an inline frame and reload the frame, of course that would require to use some server side (like php) and a query string to build the object with the new values... add this lines to the function: object.parenNode.removeChild(object); document.getElementById('streamHolder').appendChild(object);

Comment: il look around with the codes tomorrow. thanks for all the help so far. you got me further then i have gotten by my self in a month. :)